# All fields in DDL sql view of abap cds is a primary key. How can I make fields a non key?

Tags: abap, cds

I have created a cds view. I need to use the backend table but all the fields in SE11 are shown as key fields.

What I noticed is that only if I am using fields that were 'CAST' then this happens, without it only the first two fields are keys.

Comment: by backend table you mean CDS-generated SQL view? give the screenshot and the code of your view and your table

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adding
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true

and then setting keys manually.

It seems if we use cast or aggregation, SAP by default makes all fields as primary key.